# Как подключить к проекту в CLion статически Qt5 через CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, makefile

Скачал исходники, скомпилировал с флагом `-static` в `/usr/local/Qt5_static/` . Создал пустой проект, где буду использовать Qt, изменил `CMakeLists.txt` до состояния:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Splines)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -static -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -v")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/local/Qt5_static/")
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

add_executable(Splines ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Splines Qt5::Widgets)
```

Выдаёт ошибку линковки:

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.0'
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Splines.dir/build.make:124: /home/darthvlado/MEGA/MEGAsync/workspace/ClionProjects/Splines/Splines] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/Splines.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Ошибка 2
```

Очевидно, вместо указанного мной пути пытается добавить shared-библиотеку и фейлится. Пробовал некоторые другие варианты, в таком случае ошибку выдаёт сам cmake ещё до сборки.

Как правильно прилинковать статически Qt5 через cmake?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов подключить Qt с модулями.

**1.Самый простой:**

```
add_library(LibName STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET LibName PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${path_to_lib})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(programName LibName)
```

Так же не забудте добавить инклуды.

**2.Самый старый**

```
set(Qt5Widgets_DIR "/usr/local/Qt5_static/")#или задавать префикс
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
qt5_use_modules(Splines Widgets)
```

**3.Новый и самый правильный.**

Если CMake 2.8.11 и старше.

```
set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/local/Qt5_static/")
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)
target_link_libraries(Splines Qt5::Widgets)
```

Начиная с Qt 5.7 нужно C++11.
Включается либо флагами как сделали вы(у вас С++14).

Либо:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Comment: `find_package` может искать и статические библиотеки, все зависит только от того, как написан `Find<name>.cmake`

Comment: @PavelParshin Он может делать всё тоже самое что и cmake но find_package написан не для статика. А подключать модуль написанный для статика к find_package это костыль.

Comment: Где это написано, что `find_package` только для поиска динамических зависимостей? Посмотрите, например, стандартный модуль поиска Boost: если выставить флаг `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, то будут искаться статические библиотеки.

Comment: @PavelParshin хоть я и считаю это костылём но вы правы. нашёл ряд проектов которые так делают и посмотрел find файл(надо было с его просмотра начинать). Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать значение переменной Qt5Widgets_DIR

```
/usr/local/Qt5_static/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
```

путь может отличаться